# Gulp.src Glob Won't Copy .csscomb.json File

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob

I am trying to copy `.csscomb.json` over to my `dest` folder.  Everything works and copies over, but the .csscomb.json does not.  **When I gulp.src the name specifically - it works.**  Does anyone know why? I am thinking it has to do with the period at the beginning of the name.

Below is a paired down version of the Gulp Task.  The .csscomb is in the root folder.

Doesn't work...

```
 gulp.task('copy', function() {
            gulp.src('./**/*')
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
                .pipe(notify('Folders Copied finished'));
        });
```

This works...

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
            gulp.src('.csscomb.json')
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
                .pipe(notify('Folders Copied finished'));
        });
```

Also, when .csscomb is clumped in Gulp.src it doesn't work -

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
        gulp.src(['**/*', '.csscomb.json',
                        '!*.html',
                        '!js/',
                        '!js/**',
                        '!dist/',
                        '!dist/**',
                        '!styles/',
                        '!styles/**',
                        '!img/',
                        '!img/**']'./**/*')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
            .pipe(notify('Folders Copied finished'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glob() does list "hidden" files (files starting with . including the directories . and ..), but only if you explicitly ask it for.  I guess it makes sense - as in you don't want all the hidden stuff with /.*

So for example... `'app/.htaccess'`